# Simplifying 4 double summations

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have 4 double summations added together that are all very similar, but I don't know if it is possible to simplify all of it:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^b \sin(\sqrt{(n\alpha+x)^2+([b-n]\alpha+y)^2})+\sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^b \sin(\sqrt{(n\alpha-x)^2+([b-n]\alpha+y)^2}) \\
&+\sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^b \sin(\sqrt{(n\alpha+x)^2+([b-n]\alpha-y)^2})+\sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^b \sin(\sqrt{(n\alpha-x)^2+([b-n]\alpha-y)^2})
\end{align}

I know it looks very messy at first, but it is essentially just one of the summations, but with all 4 variations on the signs that have been changed; I'm hoping, but struggling, to find that many of it will cancel out.

If the infinity presents problems, a finite bound may be set (it's for a model).

*Answer given hasn't simplified it to one double-sum as far as I've tried; help still needed please :)

Comment: What are $\alpha,x,y$?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry: the whole thing is a function of x and y, so they are variables, whilst alpha is a constant.

Comment: It seems the insides are the distance from a fixed point for each iteration. At each iteration, the fixed point is moved and scaled. Try looking for some form of symmetry.

Comment: Impressive! It's essentially a very basic model for a ripple tank with oscillations in the centre of a square with sides alpha (though I haven't included coefficients for a decrease in amplitude with distance, or when the waves reflect).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to collapse the four double-sums into one double-sum by using
$$
\sin(a) + \sin(b) =
2 \sin \left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right)\cos \left(\frac{a-b}{2} \right)
$$
a few times.

Comment: I can do that to 2 pairs of double-sums, so that I have 2sin(a)cos(b)+2sin(c)+(d), but I can't simplify any further, so at best I can have 2 double-sums, not one. Ideally I want something where I can differentiate it and find the conditions required for roots, and also where I can differentiate it twice for stationary points (I'm feeling numerical methods may be required at this stage).

Comment: *2sin(c)cos(d) (wont let me edit)

Comment: (1) You should have mentioned that in your original post, because that might affect how you solve the problem that you want to solve. (2) I'm not sure you can find all of the roots, because sin(x) is -1 infinitely often. (3) That sin of a distance looks strange; you're sure you've got the right function?

Comment: (2) I see... if I include limits, let's say x and y are between -alpha and alpha, then there won't be infinite roots; here's a graph of it for up to b=1 goo.gl/8NWruZ (I can't fit in summations without wolfram alpha pro). (3) I'm fairly sure as it looks as I was expecting on the graph.